# Normal map baking artefacts

Tags: texture-baking, normals, baking, normal-map

I created a simple Hight-poly and Low-poly geometry. when baking Normal, I get strange artifacts. I tried to change the settings, extrusion,used cage. without result. Explain how to deal with them. maybe I'm doing something wrong. Blender_2.83 (2.8-2.83 - working same)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. You need to bake 32 bit image (and save in 16 bit PNG for example)